# Given matrix $T$, determine whether vector $\mathbf{v}$ is in $R(T)$.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand a problem like the one given below, but I am having trouble understanding? May someone provide me with an example of how to solve a problem like this?

> Define a linear operator $T\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by
>   $$
> T\left(\,\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\,\right)
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \begin{alignat}{3}
> x&+{}&&\phantom{{}+{}}2z\\
> 2x&+y&&+3z\\x&-y&&+3z
> \end{alignat}
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Determine whether the vector $\mathbf{v}$ is in $R(T)$ (range of $T$)
>   $$
> \mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}
> $$

Comment: What do you mean by $R (T) $.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima The range of T. Also I tried to add the image in the question, but I don't know how? So I added the link that Mathexhange allows.

Comment: Compute $T (1,1,0) $.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Did you pick random numbers to plug into x,y,z?

Comment: We look for $x,y,z $ such that $T (x,y,z)=(1,3,0) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer in an algorithmic way: the criterion for a vector to be in the range of a linear map is testing if the augmented matrix has the same rank as  the matrix of the linear map:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&|&1\\2&1&3&|&3\\1&-1&3&|&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&|&1\\0&1&-1&|&1\\0&-1&1&|&-1\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&|&1\\0&1&-1&|&1\\0& 0 &0&|&0\end{bmatrix}$$
We see both matrices have the same rank ($2$), hence yes, the vector  is in the range ot $T$. Further more the last form of the augmented matrix contain the information that the solutions are:
$$x=1-2z, \enspace y=1+z.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The given vector $[1,3,0]^T$ stay in the range if the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{3}
x&+{}&&\phantom{{}+{}}2z=1\\
2x&+y&&+3z=3\\
x&-y&&+3z=0
\end{alignat}
\end{cases}
$$
has a solution.

Comment: So it seems like you set it equal to the transformation?

Comment: Yes, to be in the range means that it is the resut of the transformation applied to some vector.

Comment: Oh I see so I must setup an augmented matrix, and then solve to see if it have a solution. I now understand, but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes that's OK, or you can solve the system with any other method.

Answer (score 1):

Let us look for $(x,y,z):$

$$x+2z=1$$

$$2x+y+3z=3$$

$$x-y+2z=0$$

this gives $y=x+2z $

and
$$x+2z=y=1$$

we can take $$x=y=1,z=0$$

Comment: I believe I understand more now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of checking this would be as follows. Note that $T$ is given by
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 2\\ 2 & 1 &3 \\ 1 &-1 &3 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now, form the augmented matrix

$$
\widetilde{T} = \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 2 &1\\ 2 & 1 &3  &3 \\ 1 &-1 &3 &0 \end{bmatrix}. = \left[T \  \begin{bmatrix}1 \\3\\0 \end{bmatrix}\right].
$$

The system above has a solution if and only if $rank(T) = rank(\widetilde{T})$.